# Recurring payments with ActiveMerchant + Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, activemerchant

Has anyone used the ActiveMerchant Stripe gateway to process recurring/subscription payments?  If so, I'd love to see a code example.

There are a few references to 'recurring' in the gateway's source - https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant/blob/master/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/stripe.rb, but I haven't been able to successfully supply a plan as described at https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions.

Stripe has a Ruby gem, but I'd prefer to use ActiveMerchant b/c my Rails app is already using several other payment gateways.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stripe implementation at ActiveMerchant doesn't support recurring/subscription payments. In fact, most of the ActiveMerchant gateways integrations are with Shopify in mind. And 99.99% of Shopify transactions are one time transactions.
Take a look at the PayPal recurring solution at ActiveMerchant and you'll realize AM hasn't been focused at all on subscriptions.
Disclaimer: I work at [MONEI.](http://monei.net)